# Accessibility insights not showing children of Firefox "open with" dialog when it is opened after "File Upload" dialog

Tags: accessibility-api, accessibility-insights, accessibility-inspector

Use case:-

1. Click on Browse button
2. This will open a file upload dialog - Inspect this dialog with accessibility insights - All the dialog properties and its children are showing
3. Close file upload and click on Download button to download the file
4. This will open an "Open with" dialog - Inspect this dialog with accessibility insights - Only the Dialog root element and title bar are showing. Dialog children are not showing.

Failed:-
[image: Failed scenario]

Expected:-
[image: Success scenario]

When the "file upload" dialog is not opened before the "open with" dialog, accessibility insights show all the properties & children of the "open with" dialog.

We have a C++ application that uses accessibility insights API to get dialog properties and programmatically click on dialog buttons.

Windows:- Windows Server 2019, version - 1809, OS build -17763.5329
Firefox:- 102.15.1 esr 64-bit

Please help.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error on my machine. What happens if you click the flask icon next to the "window 'Opening Att.txt'", and then click on "View results in the UI automation tree" in the upper right? (Also, may I suggest upgrading your Firefox ESR if possible - 102.15.1 ESR support ended 5 months ago).

Comment: "View results in the UI automation tree" is also not showing all the properties of dialog.

Comment: Hm. First step is probably upgrading the Firefox. Also, what is it you are trying to do? You might achieve it in another way, for example if you change things in the Firefox config (e.g. via `about:config`) instead. Or if you are trying to find out the file type, you can actually do a HTTP request to the download link instead and read the response from the server, things like that.